# Enviar datos con redirect con cakePHP Version 2

Tags: php, cakephp

Con el método redirect, cambio de controlador y vista, pero quiero q antes que cambien envié un parámetro, pero no se como recibirlo en el otro controlador, los datos los envia por la url, pero es algo raro no usa el signo "?" sino ":"

URL: http://localhost/cakephp/Joshuas/vista/parametro:HolaUno/parametro2:Holados

Método que redirecciona al otro controlador y envía los datos (parametro, parametro1).

```
 return $this->redirect(
        array('controller' => 'Joshuas',
            'action' => 'vista',
            'parametro' => 'HolaUno',
            'parametro2' => 'Holados')
    );
```

llegan a esta clase y así intento recibir parametros:

```
<?php
```

class JoshuasController extends AppController{

```
public function vista(){
    $variable = $_GET['parametro'];
    $variable1 = $_GET['parametro1'];

}
```

}

Pero me da este error

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: parametro [APP\Controller\JoshuasController.php, line 6]
```

Notice (8): Undefined index: parametro1 [APP\Controller\JoshuasController.php, line 7]

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguientes pasos en tu `public function vista()`:

**1.** Define un parámetro dentro de la función vista(una variable que recibe los datos que está enviando a través del método `redirect()`)

```
public function vista($parametro, $parametro2){
    $variable = $parametro;
    $variable1 = $parametro2;
}
```

**2.** Agrega lo siguiente al final de tu `public function vista()`:

`$this->set('variable','variable1');`

Espero sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias(Y)